# How to import mySQL dump file into MySQL lower version?

Tags: database, mysql-workbench, mysql, mysql-error-1064

On My local machine has mysql version  5.7 and web hosting has a lower version of mySQL.
Below is a screenshot of my hosting version mysql information.

Please tell me how to Export so that it should be compatible with my hosting Server version ? 
I am using workbench

[image: MySql webhosting information]
This is the error

[image]

however there is no syntax error when I try to import on same machine

Comment: what is the error you are getting ?

Comment: @MohdSayeed I have attached an Image of the error. Please check

Comment: just remove length from date time (remove `6` ) its not required.

Comment: @MohdSayeed , That won't work , As that's not the only incompatible syntax. And Replacing Syntax for million of lines is a nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replaced all incompatible syntax with MySQL 5.5 syntax, It was harsh to do it with plain editors , so I worte my own console application to convert it, Anyway if someone face this issue , Try replacing each and every incompatible syntax with 5.5 syntax :P